# Javascript error with bare google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've got a really basic google maps page. But even so I'm getting a JavaScript error. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the entire source

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #map_canvas { height: 650px; margin-right: 400px; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(60.48430, 15.43397),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        function initialize() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I get in Chrome's JavaScript console is:

```
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=host:localhost%…51x41.79199,size:951x650,relsize:1.07,token:86jb1bay0n,src:apiv3,ts:bwqiga
(anonymous function) maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=host:localhost%3A8000,…x41.79199,size:951x650,relsize:1.07,token:86jb1bay0n,src:apiv3,ts:bwqiga:1
```

I serve the html page with a local web server and access it at localhost:8080/polyline.html
It's just a quick "python -m SimpleHTTPServer" in the dir the html file is in.

Just tested to directly access the html file (i.e. not serving it with the python webserver, but rather accessing it at file:///) and just as @brouxhaha said, no errors are present.

So, what do I need to do to get rid of that error when using my web server?

**EDIT:** I put the code in [a gist](https://gist.github.com/Tobbe/78b61dcbdf00bff44bf0). You can access it as a proper web page here: http://rawgithub.com/Tobbe/78b61dcbdf00bff44bf0/raw/928d217efb353f8fd026248e67e0e87e8a2cca4c/polyline.html

The error is present at the url above too.

Comment: Must be an issue with your local server. I just copied and pasted into a blank html file and opened it locally (no server). No js errors here.

Comment: Added a bit more info on the server. It's just "python -m SimpleHTTPServer"